# PHP date string or array

Tags: php, date

I need to get two variables from a birth date entered by the user, one for the month they were born and one for the day in numerical form. I also needed the age, but was already able to solve that.

I tried,

```
$birthday="12/22/1980";
$month=$birthday(0);
$day=$birthday(1);

$month=$birthday(m);
$day=$birthday(d);

$month=date($birthday 0);
$day=date($birthday 1);
```

Comment: Sidenote: If that is your actual code, you're missing a semi-colon in `$birthday="12/22/1980"` <= so modify your code if you are using a closing `;`

Comment: I don't understand your code and your question... where is the question

Comment: Thank you fred and i do have the semi colon,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode your string into an array with `explode`, and with `list` you can assign several vars.

Code will look like this:

```
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $birthday);
```

Comment: explanation would be great, of course code solves probably his problem